# Is there a way to continue printing a random element from a Python 3 dictionary without repeating?

Tags: python, random

I am currently learning Python 3, as well as trying to pickup on command line along the way.
I figured I could practice both by writing a Python program to aid in memorizing commands for the command line.

The code I wrote *almost* did what I wanted it to (shown below).

Essentially, when I run the file in my command line, I want it to print a random key from the dictionary, then allow me to type in what I think it means, then show me the correct answer upon hitting enter.

The problem is that it just keeps printing the same key every time unless I close the program and run it again.
I've tried functions, nesting functions, for loops, while loops, nesting loops, etc and I just can't seem to get it to print a different key.

I would love some feedback on this!

```
import random
import time

command_dict = {
    'pwd' : 'print working directory',
    'hostname': 'my computer\'s network name',
    'mkdir' : 'make directory',
    'cd' : 'change directory',
    'ls' : 'list directory',
    'rmdir' : 'remove directory',
    'pushd' : 'push directory',
    'popd' : 'pop directory',
    'cp' : 'copy a file or directory',
    'mv' : 'move file or directory',
    'less' : 'page through a file',
    'cat' : 'print the whole file',
    'xargs' : 'execute arguments',
    'find' : 'find files',
    'grep' : 'find things inside files',
    'man' : 'read a manual page',
    'apropos' : 'find which man page is appropriate',
    'env' : 'look at your environment',
    'echo' : 'print some arguments',
    'export' : 'export/set a new environment variable',
    'exit' : 'exit the shell',
    'sudo' : 'become super user root - !Danger!'
}

random_key = random.sample(list(command_dict), 1)[0]
answer_value = command_dict.get(random_key)

while True:

    print(random_key)
    input("> ")
    print("ANSWER: ", answer_value)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n------------")
```

[here is my command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LLLE.png)

Comment: You don't call `random.sample` within your `while` loop, so of course the value is the same every time

Comment: Insert the 2 lines beginning with `random_key` after the last `print`, but still in the while loop

Comment: You choose the `random_key` once then you loop and print it repeatedly. You should try to move that part in the loop.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: An alternative for getting a random item: `k,v = random.sample(command_dict.items(),1)[0]`

Comment: Don't use `random.sample` where `random.choice` will do.

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to use Ankidroid for flashcards instead. This way you'll just be reviewing the same commands that you already know, whereas using a flashcards app lets you mark certain cards as "I already memorized this", so you don't have to waste time looking at them. There's probably a deck for command line tools already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a different key each time, just keep a list of still available keys and remove the one just chosen. When the list of available keys gets empty, fill it again. `random.choice()` chooses just one key (similar to `random.sample(..., 1)[0]`).

```py
available_keys = []
while True:
    if not available_keys:  # refill the list of available keys every time it gets empty
        available_keys = list(command_dict)
    random_key = random.choice(available_keys)
    available_keys.remove(random_key)  # remove the chosen key to prevent it gets chosen again
    print (random_key)
    input ("> ")
    print ("ANSWER: ", command_dict.get(random_key))
    time.sleep (2)
    print ("\n------------")
```